# grep with continuation lines

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, grep

How can I `grep`/`awk`/`sed` a file looking for some pattern, and print the entire line (including continuation lines if the matched line ends with `\`?

File `foo.txt` contains:

```
something
whatever
thisXXX line \
    has a continuation line
blahblah
a \
multipleXXX \
continuation \
line
```

What should I execute to get (not necessarily in one line, not necessarily removing multiple spaces):

```
thisXXX line has a continuation line
a multipleXXX continuation line
```

BTW I'm using bash and fedora21, so it does not need to be POSIX-compliant (but I'll appreciate a solution if it is POSIX)

Comment: Do you want the search to span over continuation lines? i.e. if you're searching for `hello`, does `hel\␤lo` match?

Comment: @gilles, yes, same as with sh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach using perl to remove newlines that are preceded by `\` and whitespace:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\\\n/ /' file | grep XXX
thisXXX line      has a continuation line
a  multipleXXX  continuation  line
```

To remove extra spaces, pass it through sed:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\\\n/ /' file | grep XXX | sed 's/  */ /g'
thisXXX line has a continuation line
a multipleXXX continuation line
```

Comment: Since the backslash is supposed to be the last char before the newline, you can remove `\s*`. And you don't need the `g` flag

Comment: @glennjackman not sure I understand. I need the g since I want to remove all extra spaces on the line, the OP's example has a line with multiple continuations. I don't have any `\s`.

Comment: I was commenting on your perl command, but Gilles fixed it.

Comment: @glenn so he did,  I was on mobile and completely missed it.  Thank you both.

Comment: According to the shell rules for continuation lines, `'s/\\\n/ /'` should be changed to `'s/\\\n//'`, i.e. backspace + newline should be replaced by nothing, not by a space.

Comment: @vinc17 if there is no trailing space in the first line, you will change `hello\nworld` to `helloworld` instead of `hello world`. That's why I want to replace with a space.

Comment: @terdon But this is not the correct rule. For instance, if you type `echo "foo\`, then Enter, then `bar"` in a shell, you get `foobar`, not `foo bar`. If you want a space between `foo` and `bar`, then put one either before the backslash or at the beginning of the second line (just before `bar`).

Comment: @vnc but why are you thinking about shell commands? The question doesn't mention shell commands, the file's extension doesn't suggest a shell script and the OP's example is words, not code. You would be right for code, of course, but this doesn't seem to be about code.

Answer (score 5):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -ne 'if (/\\$/) { $l .= $_ }
          else { print $l, $_ if $l =~ /XXX/;
                 $l = "";
          }' foo.txt
```

`$l` works as an accumulator. `-n` processes the input line by line (cf. sed), if the line ends in a backslash, it's added to the accumulator, if not, the accumulator plus the line is printed provided it matches XXX, and the accumulator is emptied.

Answer (score 5):

With POSIX sed:

```
$ sed -e '
:1
/\\$/{N
  s/\n//              
  t1
}
/\\/!d 
s/\\[[:blank:]]*//g
' file
```

Comment: @don_crissti Pipe this into `grep XXX`

Comment: @don_crissti: I don't see matching `XXX` in requirement.

Comment: @Gilles - no, it doesn't work like that. Change OP's input replacing `something` with `XXX` (without a trailing backslash) on first line and then try piping this `sed` command to `grep`. You won't get the `XXX` line in the final output. _choroba_'s solution fails in a similar manner while _jimmij_'s prints the second line too (it shouldn't).

Answer (score 5):

With `pcregrep` without changing structure of the lines:

```
pcregrep -M '^(.|\\\n)*XXX(.|\n)*?[^\\]$' file
```

Comment: As long as a backslash + newline cannot appear in the regexp XXX, this is a nice solution as it can be used recursively with `-r` (with the other solutions, one would need to use `find` in such a case). There is only a possible issue with `[^\\]$` if the matched text is at the end of the file. I think that this should be corrected to `'^(\\\n|.)*XXX(\\\n|.)*'` (with `\\\n` before `.`).

Comment: I meant: As long as a backslash + newline cannot appear in the text that should be matched. Indeed, as said in a comment to the question, when searching for `hello`, `hel\␤lo` should match. In such a case, this would need to introduce `(\\\n)*` at each "point" of the regexp!

Answer (score 4):

My twist:

```
perl -0777 -ne '                           # read the entire file into $_
    s{ [[:blank:]]* \\ \n [[:blank:]]* }   # join continued lines
     { }gx;
    print grep {/XXX/} split /(?<=\n)/     # print the matching lines
' foo.txt
```

```
thisXXX line has a continuation line
a multipleXXX continuation line
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd say [Perl is the simplest here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/207579). It isn't POSIX, though it's in the default installation of most non-embedded unices. If you want POSIX, use awk.

```
awk '{if (/\\$/) printf "%s" $0; else print}'
```

This collapses continuation lines. If you want to find patterns that spread over a continuation, pipe this into grep. If you want to match only uninterrupted patterns, let awk accumulate continued lines and do the matching.

```
awk '{
    if (sub(/\\$/,"")) {
        line = line $0;
    } else {
        if (/XXX/) print;
        line = "";
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a small improvement to Gilles awk solution (thanks Gilles!), but does require nawk:

```
nawk '{if (/\\$/) {$0=substr($0,1,length($0)-2); printf "%s",$0} else print}'
```

This will create a continuous line if the line wraps, but does not include the "\" and space character. (I found this helpful when grepping for PATH statements since the "\" can lead to confusion when interpreting the results.)